# Quick Python method to get neighbouring elements in 2D grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a method somewhere in a Python package that returns the elements and/ or indexes of an element in a 2d grid. E.g. if we have:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],

 [5, 6, 7, 8],

 [7, 8, 9, 0]]
```

..and we give the method the index `[0,1]` it should return `[1, 6, 3]` (if it could return `[[0,0], [1,1], [0,2]]` that would be even better) and giving it `[1,1]` would return `[5, 2, 8, 7]` (or the corresponding indexes- order isn't important).

There is obviously the simple solution to this, however, it's too slow since I want to do this on a large scale for arrays with several thousand elements. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: [0,1] points to the element with value 2, who's neighboring values are 1, 6 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it too slow?

From the input coordinate [a, b] return the list [[a-1, b], [a+1, b], [a, b-1], [a, b+1]], avoiding coordinates outside your grid.